# Why does $\hat Q(\lambda )$ has $\mu $ as an eigenvalue with geometricmultiplicty equal to $k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In [this paper Page 19](http://www.math.ntua.gr/~ppsarr/mcblp.pdf)

Why does $\hat Q (\lambda )$ has $\mu $ as an eigenvalue with geometricmultiplicty equal to $k$?

Comment: You need to present a self-contained question which uses as little of the context from the paper as possible. In this case I think it *might* be sufficient to define $\hat{Q}(\lambda),\mu$ and $k$, but I am not sure, because it seems to take a fair bit of work to get up to equations 13-17, which we MSE users should not have to do ourselves. Still, those three things are definitely necessary; we're not going to hunt for those three definitions.

Comment: @Ian - Is it  enough to prove that $\dim (\det (\hat Q(\mu ))) = k$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but presumably it is just a restatement of the definition of geometric multiplicity.